# Puedo usar javascript combinado con instrucciones de Genexus

Tags: javascript, genexus, genexus15, genexusxev3

Por ejemplo con javascript identificar si el tamaño dela pantalla es mayor a 992 px, y si es mayor no mostrar un textBlock
Ejemplo
`Textblock1.Caption='<script> if (screen.width>=992){'+ TextBlock2.Visible=true + '}</script>'`

Me marca un **error spc0009:Type mismatch in expression: ' if (screen.width>=992){'+ TextBlock2.Visible.(web panel 'abcd'...)'**

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este código lo puedes lograr:

```
Textlock1.Caption = "<script> if (screen.width>=992){document.getElementById(" + 
'"TEXTBLOCK2"' + ").style.display = 'none';}</script>"
```

Siempre suponiendo que el textblock que quieras ocultar se llame Textblock2 en Genexus. De otra forma, debes buscar el ID que se le asigna al elemento HTML que quieras ocultar.